# foreach loop can not cast type to the interface it implements

Tags: c#, exception, covariance

### Edited with complete, working, code-example.

In my IRC app, the application receives content from an IRC server. The content is sent in to a factory and the factory spits out an `IMessage` object that can be consumed by the presentation layer of the application. The `IMessage` interface and a single implementation is shown below.

```
public interface IMessage
{
    object GetContent();
}

public interface IMessage<out TContent> : IMessage where TContent : class
{
    TContent Content { get; }
}

public class ServerMessage : IMessage<string>
{
    public ServerMessage(string content)
    {
        this.Content = content;
    }

    public string Content { get; private set; }

    public object GetContent()
    {
        return this.Content;
    }
}
```

To receive the `IMessage` object, the presentation layer subscribes to notifications that are published within my domain layer. The notification system iterates over a collection of subscribers to a specified `IMessage` implementation and fires a callback method to the subscriber.

```
public interface ISubscription
{
    void Unsubscribe();
}

public interface INotification<TMessageType> : ISubscription where TMessageType : class, IMessage
{
    void Register(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback);
    void ProcessMessage(TMessageType message);
}

internal class Notification<TMessage> : INotification<TMessage> where TMessage : class, IMessage
{
    private Action<TMessage, ISubscription> callback;

    public void Register(Action<TMessage, ISubscription> callbackMethod)
    {
        this.callback = callbackMethod;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        this.callback = null;
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(TMessage message)
    {
        this.callback(message, this);
    }
}

public class NotificationManager
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<ISubscription>> listeners =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<ISubscription>>();

    public ISubscription Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback) where TMessageType : class, IMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(TMessageType);

        // Create our key if it doesn't exist along with an empty collection as the value.
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            listeners.TryAdd(messageType, new List<ISubscription>());
        }

        // Add our notification to our listener collection so we can publish to it later, then return it.
        var handler = new Notification<TMessageType>();
        handler.Register(callback);

        List<ISubscription> subscribers = listeners[messageType];
        lock (subscribers)
        {
            subscribers.Add(handler);
        }

        return handler;
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class, IMessage
    {
        Type messageType = message.GetType();
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Exception is thrown here due to variance issues.
        foreach (INotification<T> handler in listeners[messageType])
        {
            handler.ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to demonstrate how the above code works, I have a simple Console application that subscribes to notifications from the above `ServerMessage` type. The console app first publishes by passing the `ServerMessage` object in to the `Publish<T>` method directly. This works without any issues.

The 2nd example has the app creating an IMessage instance using a factory method. The IMessage instance is then passed in to the `Publish<T>` method, causing my variance issue to throw an `InvalidCastException`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var notificationManager = new NotificationManager();
        ISubscription subscription = notificationManager.Subscribe<ServerMessage>(
            (message, sub) => Console.WriteLine(message.Content));

        notificationManager.Publish(new ServerMessage("This works"));
        IMessage newMessage = MessageFactoryMethod("This throws exception");
        notificationManager.Publish(newMessage);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IMessage MessageFactoryMethod(string content)
    {
        return new ServerMessage(content);
    }
}
```

The exception states that I can not cast an `INotification<IMessage>` (what the Publish method is understands the message being published to be) in to an `INotification<ServerMessage>`.

I have tried to mark the INotification interface generic as contravariant, like `INotification<in TMessageType>` but can't do that because I'm consuming `TMessageType` as a parameter to the `Register` method's callbacks. Should I split the interface in to two separate interfaces? One that can register and one that can consume? Is that the best alternative?

Any additional help on this would be great.

Comment: Usually when you see an exception where it says that you can't cast something to another that appears to have the same exact type, it means that you redefined the class with the same name in a different assembly.  You must use the same types defined in the same assemblies and have them reference the one definition.

Comment: This question has been asked hundreds of times. The keyword you want to look for is covariance.

Comment: @EricLippert I  mentioned covariance being what I thought the issue was in my post. I just wasn't sure how to resolve the problem

Comment: Is a bowl of apples the same thing as a bowl of fruit? No. You can put a banana into a bowl of fruit but not into a bowl of apples. That's the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding another level of indirection. Having followed advice from @PeterDuniho, I broke apart the `INotification<TMessage>` interface in to two separate interfaces. By adding the new `INotificationProcessor` interface, I can change my collection of listeners from an `ISubscription` to an `INotificationProcessor` and then iterate over my collection of listeners as an INotificationProcessor.

```
public interface ISubscription
{
    void Unsubscribe();
}

public interface INotification<TMessageType> : ISubscription where TMessageType : class, IMessage
{
    void Register(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback);
}

public interface INotificationProcessor
{
    void ProcessMessage(IMessage message);
}
```

The `INotificationProcessor` implementation, implements both `INotificationProcessor` and `INotification<TMessageType>`. This allows the `Notification` class below to cast the IMessage provided in to the appropriate generic type for publication.

```
internal class Notification<TMessage> : INotificationProcessor, INotification<TMessage> where TMessage : class, IMessage
{
    private Action<TMessage, ISubscription> callback;

    public void Register(Action<TMessage, ISubscription> callbackMethod)
    {
        this.callback = callbackMethod;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        this.callback = null;
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        // I can now cast my IMessage to T internally. This lets
        // subscribers use this and not worry about handling the cast themselves. 
        this.callback(message as TMessage, this);
    }
}
```

My `NotificationManager` can now hold a collection of `INotificationProcessor` types instead of `ISubscription` and invoke the `ProcessMessage(IMessage)` method regardless if what comes in to it is an `IMessage` or a `ServerMessage`.

```
public class NotificationManager
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<INotificationProcessor>> listeners =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<INotificationProcessor>>();

    public ISubscription Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback) where TMessageType : class, IMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(TMessageType);

        // Create our key if it doesn't exist along with an empty collection as the value.
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            listeners.TryAdd(messageType, new List<INotificationProcessor>());
        }

        // Add our notification to our listener collection so we can publish to it later, then return it.
        var handler = new Notification<TMessageType>();
        handler.Register(callback);

        List<INotificationProcessor> subscribers = listeners[messageType];
        lock (subscribers)
        {
            subscribers.Add(handler);
        }

        return handler;
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class, IMessage
    {
        Type messageType = message.GetType();
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Exception is thrown here due to variance issues.
        foreach (INotificationProcessor handler in listeners[messageType])
        {
            handler.ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The original app example now works without issue.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var notificationManager = new NotificationManager();
        ISubscription subscription = notificationManager.Subscribe<ServerMessage>(
            (message, sub) => Console.WriteLine(message.Content));

        notificationManager.Publish(new ServerMessage("This works"));
        IMessage newMessage = MessageFactoryMethod("This works without issue.");
        notificationManager.Publish(newMessage);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IMessage MessageFactoryMethod(string content)
    {
        return new ServerMessage(content);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Looks good. One minor suggestion: where you cast, as in `message as TMessage`, I would recommend using a regular cast, not the `as` operator. I.e. `(TMessage)message`. This way, if there _is_ a coding error at some point, you get an actual `InvalidCastException` instead of `NullReferenceException`. And the exception happens at the earliest point of failure, rather than inside the callback method.

Comment: Thanks, I was planning on performing `message as TMessage` within the `ProcessMessage` method. I would perform a null check prior to invoking the callback with the message and throwing an invalid cast exception myself with information of the IMessage type and the generic type to help with debugging when the exception happens.

Answer (score 2):

The basic issue here is that you are trying to use your types in a variant way, but that's not supported for the syntax you are trying to use. Thanks to your updated and now complete (and nearly minimal) code example, it's also clear that you simply can't do this the way you have it written now.

The interface in question, and in particular the method you want to use (i.e. `ProcessMessage()`, *could* in fact be declared as a covariant interface (if you split the `Register()` method into a separate interface). But doing so would not solve your problem.

You see, the issue is that you are trying to assign an implementation of `INotification<ServerMessage>` to a variable typed as `INotification<IMessage>`. Note that once that implementation is assigned to the variable of that type, the caller could pass *any* instance of `IMessage` to the method, even one that is not an instance of `ServerMessage`. But the actual implementation expects (nay, demands!) an instance of `ServerMessage`.

In other words, the code you are trying to write simply is not statically safe. It has no way at compile time to guarantee that the types match, and that's just not something C# is willing to do.

One option would be to weaken the type-safety of the interface, by making it non-generic. I.e. just have it always accept an `IMessage` instance. Then each implementation would have to cast according to its needs. Coding errors would be caught only at run-time, with an `InvalidCastException`, but correct code would run fine.

Another option would be to set the situation up so that the full type parameter is known. For example, make `PushMessage()` generic method too, so that it can call `Publish()` using the type parameter of `ServerMessage` instead of `IMessage`:

```
private void OnMessageProcessed(IrcMessage message, IrcCommand command, ICommandFormatter response)
{
    this.OnMessageProcessed(message);
    ServerMessage formattedMessage = (ServerMessage)response.FormatMessage(message, command);
    this.PushMessage(formattedMessage);
}

private void PushMessage<T>(T notification) where T : IMessage
{
    this.notificationManager.Publish(notification);
}
```

That way, the type parameter `T` would match exactly in the `foreach` loop where you're having the problem.

Personally, I prefer the second approach. I realize that in your current implementation, this doesn't work. But IMHO it could be worth revisiting the broader design to see if you can accomplish the same feature while preserving the generic type throughout, so that it can be used to ensure compile-time type safety.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't strongly type the message Type in the `OnMessageProcessed` call, as the Type is determined further up the stack using a factory. Once it comes out of my factory, the code-base just knows that it is an IMessage implementation. I updated my OP to show the INotification implementation.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: It's unfortunate you can't specify the type, but as I've described you can use interface variance to solve the problem instead.

Comment: Making the `INotification<T>` contravariant gives me a invalid variance compiler error in the interface (and its implementation) for the method `Register` (shown above). It tells me `The type parameter TMessageType must be covariantly valid on INotification<TMessageType.Register. TMessage type is contravariant.`

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: that is correct. Now that you have added some detail to your question (though I note the question _still_ does not include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), we can see that you have an additional member in your `INotification<T>` interface, where the type parameter is used contravariantly instead of covariantly. In particular, a value of type T may _exit_ (i.e. be returned by) the `Register()` method (through either the `callback` or `condition` delegate). This conflicts with the covariant declaration.

Comment: I will update my OP this evening to make it follow those guidelines.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: Possible solutions include splitting the `INotification<T>` interface into two separate interfaces, where one implements `Register()` and is contravariant (i.e. uses `out T`) and the other implements `ProcessMessage()` and is covariant (i.e. uses `in T`). Or figure out how you _can_ propagate the type parameter T to the call site, so that you don't need variance. Again, lacking a better code example it's not really possible to know for sure what would work in your case.

Comment: I have updated my original post to provide a complete, working, example source of the problem. Sadly I'm not able to propagate the type parameter down due to the `IMessage` instance being created by a factory. With the revised code-example, does your suggestion of splitting the `INotification<T>` interface in to two still make the most sense to you?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: sorry, I had your example backwards. I don't think splitting the interface works. The problem is that you have a class that accepts _only_ a `ServerMessage`, but you want to execute its method via an interface that could be passed _any_ `IMessage`. C# won't let you do this, because if it did, then you could pass some other `IMessage` (i.e. one that's not a `ServerMessage`) to the class's method, even though that class's method requires a `ServerMessage`.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: (continued...) In other words, it is possible to make `INotification<T>` covariant, but that doesn't give you the assignment legality you want. It would let you assign an instance of `INotification<IMessage>` to a variable typed as `INotification<ServerMessage>` (after all, something that is willing to accept any `IMessage` can also accept something that is a `ServerMessage`, but not the other way. You need the other way...the compiler won't let you, and for good reason. I'll update my answer to make that clear.

Comment: That's frustrating because I constrained everything to IMessage. I would expect that even though the `INotification<ServerMessage>` is what is hit in the foreach, it would know ServerMessage implements IMessage and be fine. No where in the Code-base (other than where I actually publish) knows that what came in is a ServerMessage. ServerMessage should be castable to IMessage, because it implements it :/ Clearly I struggle with understanding variance. Thanks for your update.

Comment: There's just no way for me to make my code generic all the way through-out. I have content shipped to me from an IRC server, that content is parsed by a factory and comes back as an IMessage. Since the content isn't known I can't be generic all the way through-out. At least not that I have seen, while preventing my code from having 100 if statements `if (response == 10) Publish<ServerMessage> else if (response == 101) publish<ChatMessage>` there are hundreds of response codes to check.

Comment: I suppose if I have to weaken the interface type safety then I should revert back to using events. The goal was for the presentation layer to subscribe to specific messages so it could route them to the UI differently. The presentation layer doesn't know what messages are coming in, so I'd have to Type check and cast each time which feels bad to me. I could just convert each message to an event in the API the presentation layer subscribes to. I was hoping to use this approach because of its flexibility in easily adding new message types.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: "ServerMessage should be castable to IMessage, because it implements it" -- it is. But that doesn't mean a _different_ type that contains a `ServerMessage` is automatically castable to another _different_ type that contains an `IMessage`. As I describe in my comments and in my updated answer, the ability to do that depends on which direction you are casting and which direction the values move in the type. That's where the different kinds of variance come in, and your scenario is not compatible with type-safe variance.

Comment: I have solved this problem by breaking my interface up. I posted an answer showing what was changed and how it works. I marked your answer as the answer to my question of "why doesn't the cast work" since your post answers that. My post just shows what I did to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Long stretch here, from fiddling around with the code you provided...

Using breakpoints, may I know what the method thinks T is and what the type of listeners[messageType] is?

```
foreach (Notification<T> handler in listeners[messageType])
{
    handler.ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

Because if indeed it's `Notification<IMessage>` on one side and `Notification<ServerMessage>` on the other, then yes this is an assignment compatibility issue.

There's a solution, but you have not shown code for how Notification is built.  I'll extrapolate from your current code base.  This should be all you need.

```
public interface INotification<in T> { /* interfacy stuff */ }
public class Notification<T>: INotification<T> { /* classy stuff */ }
```

Then modify the code in such a way that essentially this is called:

```
foreach (INotification<T> handler in listeners[messageType]) { /* loop stuff */ }
```

Where listeners[messageType] **must be** INotification.

This should prevent the need to cast your Notification to Notification explicitly like the compiler is complaining.

The magic occurs in the interface declaration for INotification, the **in T** key phrase (bad terminology, sorry), lets the compiler know that T is contravariant (by default, if you omit out, T is invariant, as in types must match).

**EDIT**: Per the comments, I have updated the answer to reflect the code that's actually written as opposed to what I *thought* was written.  This mainly means declaring INotification as contravariant (in T) as opposed to covariant (out T).

Comment: Actually, `INotification<T>` should be _contravariant_, and declared as `INotification<in T>`.

Comment: point taken.  I had wrongly imagined that INotification exposed a property of type T instead of exposing a function that takes a parameter of type T, like indicated in the code above.

Comment: I updated my OP to show the INotification interface & implementation. The post was becoming lengthy so I had omitted it originally.

Comment: Also, `messageType` in this instance is an instance of ServerMessage. The object provided when Publish is invoked is a ServerMessage along with the generic type provided when registering for notifications.